# Django - Custom admin save model

Tags: python, django, django-admin, save, many-to-many

I have two models: `Page` and a custom user model `MyUser`

These two models have each one a manytomanyfield:

```
class Page(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    mypages = models.ManyToManyField(Page)
    objects = UserManager()
```

When I add a member to the `members` manytomanyfield via the admin interface, I would like to add the new attributed Page object to the user automatically in the `mypages` attribute, so I am trying to override the save method of the Page model in the admin.py:

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(ModelAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
        if 'members' in form.changed_data:
        #And I am quite lost....
```

Is it a good idea? Should I do that in the "Page model custom save" method in my `models.py` file either doing it in the `admin.py`?

I tried to replace the `#And I am quite lost....` part with ideas from:

[Link1](http://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2011/11/29/many-to-many-field-save-method.html)
[Link2](http://timonweb.com/many-to-many-field-save-method-and-the-django-admin)

Without any sucess!

Answer (score 0):

This is completely mistaken. A many-to-many field is already double-ended. You don't need to define it on both ends. When you define a `members` field on `Page`, then `MyUser` will automatically get a `page_set` accessor which is the other end of the relation, and any page that adds a user to its members will automatically show up in the user's page_set. There is no need for any code.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding but I have nothing like that. When I add a new `member` object to the `members` many-to-many field of a `page` object, the many-to-many `mypages` attribute of the user is not populated with the page object! :$

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: you should **not define a mypages field at all**. The reverse accessor is called `page_set`, which is defined automatically.

Comment: I just realized that I did not understand the use of a many-to-many field. Thank you. By the way , I am gonna to edit my question and simulate this mistake, or is it better to delete the whole thread?

Comment: No, don't delete the question, it may help other people in the future.